# Setting multiple .NET SDK versions in global.json

Tags: .net, config, .net-6.0, dotnet-sdk

According to [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json) it is possible to pin down the version of SDK used in `global.json` file:

```json
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "6.0.300",
    "rollForward": "latestFeature"
  }
}
```

In my repo I have some projects using .NET6 and some other still targeting .NET5. Is it possible to pin down both `6.0.300` and `5.0.201` in the config file at the same time? Without this, all the .NET5 project start using the latest SDK5 installed on a machine.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to migrate all my projects to .NET6 now, so I don't need an answer to this anymore, but AFAIK it is not possible and only one SDK can be defined in global.json.